Simply Connected Spaces - Munkres Def
I have a small question regarding the following def. Could someone please help me out with it?
Def (by Munkres): A space $X$ is said to be simply connected if it is a path-connected space
and if $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ is the trivial (one-element) group for some $x_0 \in X$, and hence for
every $x_0 \in X$.
Question: The first part of the question implies that $\pi_1(X, x_0) = [e_{x_{0}}]$ (the constant map on $x_0$). But I do not get the second part: "and hence for
every $x_0 \in X$."
Does he mean that all fundamental groups (based at different $x  \in X $) of X (a simply connected space) are trivial?

If the space is path connected then the fundamental groups at different points are all isomorphic to each other. Pretty sure Munkres proves this before giving the definition. So if the fundamental group for one point is trivial, it follows that it is trivial for all points.

Yes. In Corollary 52.2 Munkres proved that if X is path connected and $x_0$ and $x_1$ are two points of $X$, then $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(X, x_1)$.
This implies that if $\pi_1(X, x_0)$ is trivial for some $x_0$, then all fundamental groups based at the points of $X$ are trivial.
